# How to create a raster from a CAD scan for ARCMap?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, cad, targa

I have scans of CAD streets and such and want to get a raster for georeferencing into ARCMap.
What are the easy steps to make a targa, geotiff, etc. of a known size, say 2 miles along one side as a test size scenario or any other raster format that can be imported into a layer for subsequent geo reference? Not wedded to any particular form, size, technique, format; just best practice and practical steps. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Create world files for your tiff (some geotiff contain it in the header of the file.) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t000000mp000000

Comment: Hi Mapperz, the format i have currently is jpeg, but i guess that is trivial, just save as a tiff. the problem i see is it is not geotiff and has no associated headers so the world size would be a toss up, maybe get a geotiff of the area and cut and paste the header to my new tiff? It would be nice if there was a more elegant solution as it must be a pretty common operation. Actually it was a scan of a survey map made before the dawn of the computer era, similar to a cad drawing, just not electronic format ; ).